# Joachimsthals Notations and tangents of conic at a point

Tags: conic-sections

I was going through Cut-the-Knot's ["Joachimsthal's Notations" page](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/JoachimsthalsNotations.shtml)  discussing Joachimsthal's indice method of studying conics.

> The conic can be represented in a following way:
>
> $$ s_{ij} = Ax_i x_j + B(x_i y_j + x_j y_i) + C y_i y_j + F(x_i + x_j) + G(y_i + y_j) + H=0$$
>
> Where the $i$ denotes a pair of number $(x_i,y_i)$ and $j$ also as
> $(x_j, y_j)$
>
> It is a theorem that if $(x_i,y_i)$ is a point which lies on the
> conic, then ,
>
> $$s_i = Ax_i x + B (x_i y + x y_i) + Cy_i y + F(x_i + x) + G(y_i + y) +H=0 \tag{1}$$
>
> Where I have let the pair of $(x_j,y_j)$ to be set as free variable
>
> Denotes the equation of tangent of the conic $$ s= Ax^2 +2Bxy + Cy^2 + 2Fx + 2Gy +H$$
>
> At the point $(x_i,y_i)$

My question is regarding a step in the proof of this,

> [image]

I don't get what exactly is the quantity benig plugged into (1) is, it seem the point has arguement $P(x_1,x_1)$ which doesn't make sense to me. I think the correct expression should be :

$$ P(x,y)= tP(x_1,y_1) + (1-t)P(x_2,y_2)$$

Hence the point being plugged in is given as:

$$ Q = (tx_1 + (1-t)x_2 , ty_1 + (1-t)y_2) $$

However, this seems to be still algebra bashing to move from (10) to (11), is there a more elegant approach to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't particularly *elegant*, but it helps bring some order to the chaos of the symbol-bashing.

---

Introduce $u:=1-t$ to add a touch of symmetry to the linear combination of points:
$$Q = t P(x_1,y_1) + u P(x_2,y_2) = \left(t x_1 + u x_2, t y_1 + u y_2\right) \tag1$$
Also, rewrite the quadratic expression by throwing-in convenient aliases of $1$:
$$s = A x^2 + 2 B x y + C y^2 + 2 F (t+u) x + 2 G (t+u)y + H(t+u)^2 \tag2$$
Substituting $Q$ into this form of $s$ gives an expression we can write as
$$\begin{array}{rll}
A&(\color{red}{t x_1}+\color{blue}{u x_2})&(\color{red}{t x_1}+\color{blue}{u x_2}) \\
+2B&(\color{red}{t x_1}+\color{blue}{u x_2})&(\color{red}{t y_1}+\color{blue}{uy_2}) \\
+\phantom{2}C&(\color{red}{t y_1}+\color{blue}{u y_2})&(\color{red}{t y_1}+\color{blue}{u y_2}) \\
+2F&(\color{red}{t}\;\;\;+\color{blue}{u}\;\;\;)&(\color{red}{tx_1}+\color{blue}{u x_2}) \\
+2G&(\color{red}{t}\;\;\;+\color{blue}{u}\;\;\;)&(\color{red}{ty_1}+\color{blue}{uy_2}) \\
+\;H&(\color{red}{t}\;\;\;+\color{blue}{u}\;\;\;)&(\color{red}{t}\;\;\;+\color{blue}{u}\;\;\;)
\end{array} \tag{3}$$
with which it's "easy" to gather terms by $\color{red}{t^2}$, $\color{blue}{u^2}$, and $\color{red}{t}\color{blue}{u}$ (without even explicitly expanding everything) to find
$$t^2 s_{11} + u^2s_{22} + 2 tu\, s_{12} \tag4$$
Then, Cut-the-Knot's equation $(11)$ is just the above $(4)$ after recalling that $u=1-t$. $\square$

---

**Note.** One can re-skin expression $(3)$ using the matrix form of the conic equation
$$X^TMX+NX+H$$
where
$$M:=\begin{bmatrix}A& B\\ B&C\end{bmatrix}\qquad N:=\begin{bmatrix}2F& 2G\end{bmatrix}\qquad X:=\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix}$$
Substituting-in $X=tP_1+uP_2$ (where $P_i:=(x_i,y_i)$) gives
$$(\color{red}{tP_1^T}+\color{blue}{uP_2^T})M(\color{red}{tP_1}+\color{blue}{uP_2})\;+\;N(\color{red}{t}+\color{blue}{u})(\color{red}{tP_1}+\color{blue}{uP_2})\;+\;H(\color{red}{t}+\color{blue}{u})(\color{red}{t}+\color{blue}{u}) \tag{3'}$$
where, again, it's "easy" to gather terms and get to $(4)$.

This still isn't particularly elegant, but it's a little more compact.

Comment: Hmm Nice approach, and I'm accepting it as I found the algebra managable but I hope there was an even simpler method :^)

Comment: @Buraian: I understand, and share, your disappointment. :)