# Show that the tangent to a hyperbola at any point $(x_0, y_0)$ can be described by the given equation.

Tags: calculus, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

I working on a question which I can't figure out by myself and I would like your help. It goes as follows.

Show that the tangent to a hyperbola at any point $(x_0,y_0)$
can be described by the equation $$b^{2} x_{0} x-a^{2} y_{0} y=a^{2} b^{2}$$
To do this use the general formula for a hyperbola given by:
$$\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}=1$$

**What I have already tried**

- My first thougt proces was trying to differentiate the hyperbola function implicitly to $x$, which gives you $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{b^2x_0}{a^2y_0}$ (with the point already filled in). Then I used the formula for a tangent line and solved, but althoug it looked similar it wasn't quite the same as mentioned above. I've got
  $$a^2y^2+a^2y_0y =b^2x_0x-b^2x_0^2$$
- Then I thougt I maybe didn't understand what was being asked, so maybe the point is not bounded to the curve but could be any point on the $x$ and $y$ axis. So then I solved the hyperbola function for $y$, which gave me a positive and negative solution in terms of $x$. And then I stopped because I didn't think this would me the best way.

so if anyone could help me, please do. It would be very much appreciated ;)

Comment: See, for instance, Cut-the-Knot's [Joachimsthal's Notations](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/JoachimsthalsNotations.shtml) page for the general conic; [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3980210/409) gives a proof. See also the question ["The Instant Tangent"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2361183/409).

Comment: You're nearly there:  you dropped a subscript and a sign, but you already have from $ \ y - y_0 \ = \ y'·(x - x_0) \ \ , $  $$ a^2y_0y \ - \ a^2y_0^2  \ \ = \ \ b^2x_0x \ - \ b^2x_0^2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  b^2x_0^2 \ - \ a^2y_0^2 \ \ = \ \ b^2x_0x \ - \ a^2yy_0 \ \ .  $$  The left side is equal to $ \ a^2b^2 \ \ , \ $ since the equation of the hyperbola can be written as $ \ b^2x^2 \ - \ a^2y^2 \ = \ a^2b^2 \ \ $ and applies to any point on the curve.  The equation sought follows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $$a^2y^2+a^2y_0y =b^2x_0x-b^2x_0^2\tag{1}$$

Your Eq.$(1)$ is **incorrect**.

Your slope is correct, $k=\frac{dy}{dx}|_{(x_0,y_0)}=\frac{b^2x_0}{a^2y_0}$

So the tangent line equation is:

$$y-y_0=\frac{b^2x_0}{a^2y_0}(x-x_0)$$

Simplify and we get:

$$a^2y_0y-a^2y_0^2=b^2x_0x-b^2x_0^2$$

Further:

$$b^2x_0x-a^2y_0y=b^2x_0^2-a^2y_0^2\tag{*}$$

Because $(x_0,y_0)$ is on the hyperbola, we have
$$\frac{x_0^{2}}{a^{2}}-\frac{y_0^{2}}{b^{2}}=1~~\Longrightarrow~~ b^2x_0^2-a^2y_0^2=a^2b^2$$

Plug into Eq.$(*)$

$$b^2x_0x-a^2y_0y=a^2b^2$$

We are done.

Comment: thank you, srry for the late responds. I totally forgot about my question. I really appreciate your answer :). Thank you!

Comment: No worries, glad it helps :) @TheCreator